# Manually set ng-attributes are not recognized by AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

when I set attributes for angular like tooltip-placement AngularJS won´t recognize them.

Consider that code:

```
demoApp.directive('tooltipView', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.attr("tooltip-placement", scope.placement);
            element.attr("tooltip-html-unsafe", "testtooltip");
            element.attr("tooltip-trigger", "mouseover");
        }
    };
});
```

The strange thing is when inspecting the DOM with a inspector the DOM shows those attributes but AngularJS doesn't do anything. In this case, it is not showing the tooltip.

How can I force angular to process those attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $compile if you need to process some part of the DOM (some elements and their children) and want to give it a scope.

Usage looks something like

```
$compile("<div ng-repeat='thing in stuff'>{{thing}}</div>")(someScopeWithStuffProperty)
```

So you compile a piece of code which calls the compile function for those directives which returns the link function, then for each instance of the link function the scope variable you pass through is used.

There may be some other way to trigger Angular to process some node but this is the only way I've seen so far.

http://plnkr.co/edit/L1AsEvwwVFWg12KFNhDL?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much! Where do I have to put this $compile command? I guess it has to be within the directive but at what position?

Comment: You'd want to inject $compile into your link function and use it in there if my understanding is correct.  I added a plunker to show how this can work.

Comment: I used your code. But the only thing happened was that within the dom an previously unseen attribute has shown up named: ng-isolate-scope
No elements had been added.

Why do i have to initiate an isolate scope with scope={}? I would like to use data from the parent scope.

<div tooltip-view="" class="ng-isolate-scope"> </div>

Comment: After I included the $compile-Service in the directives-stub it worked.
But do I have to use the inner scope (with scope={} ) and can I access the parents scope automatically?

Comment: Using an isolate scope shouldn't be necessary I just used one in the example to keep it simple.  Show a plunkr with your current issue and I'll try to correct it.

Comment: I added a plunkr to show what I mean.
I am trying to put some tooltip into an ID and assemble a HTML for the tooltip-html-unsafe attribut.

How can I append attributes to an element with data out of the parent scope?
Here is the plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MlqqVD?p=info

Comment: I updated my plunkr and I am now able to access data out of the scope. How can I determine the elements I wish to use?
I think it is done with an "value"-Attribut, but somehow using "html()" I receive all html-code of the element.

Comment: To be precise I only need a special HTML as string to be set into the attribute "tooltip-unsafe-html" and not more.
I have no idea how to accomplish that.

Comment: I solved the problem with an attribute of the scope using it within the link function.

Comment: Glad you got this resolved and the answer here helped apparently... sorry I wasn't able to help you along but didn't have any easy answers and have been busy.

Comment: Hey no problem, I guess you have a lot of work to be done. Thank you for your answers so far. It helped me to get in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

**Link** takes action too late, so you are not able to do changes, you'd like to.

use **$compile** API more info [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile):